# Laravel Multi tenancy

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my laravel project I am using multi tenancy. For project related work I am creating a laravel custom artisan command. I am trying to connect with repository model in that artisan command that I am creating. But I could not connect with the database. It says

Database [tenant] not configured.

How to use multi tenancy in my custom artisan command. So that I can use all the needed repository models in custom artisan command. Please suggest.

Comment: The message says you haven't configured that database connection. It should normally go in your `config/database.php`

Comment: How do you switch between your primary db and the tenant db ?

Comment: No. Tenancy is configured and its working in laravel project. But I dont know how to use connect tenancy database in custom artisan command.

Comment: I meant , If there are multiple tenants, how do you switch between them in a single source app ? How do you identify the active tenant at a given time.

Comment: Yes thats my question - Ijas Ameenudeen
How to connect with the active tenant database in my custom artisan command

Comment: You should provide the tenant to the command as a parameter and use it to configure the db conection.

Comment: @imlokeshs, I understand the question. But I asked, How do you switch between tenants in you web app since there are multiple ways? Not talking about the artisan command though.

Comment: @Ijas Ameenudeen Based on client I will switch

Comment: If you can update your answer with the 'client switching' part of your code, I can help with easy switching clients in your artisan command. Without that logic, cannot help, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using: [`hyn/multi-tenant`](https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant/)

To run specific commands you could use the `tenancy:run` command. Lets say you have a command `sync:donuts`, which needs to be run on tenant id=1.

Then you should use:

```
php artisan tenancy:run sync:donuts --tenant=1
```

[Read more in the documentation](https://laravel-tenancy.com/docs/hyn/5.4/commands#run-proxy-command)